# Kafka serialization with attribute types

Tags: java, serialization, avro

We are starting a new project based on Quarkus to write records on Kafka.

Actually, there is an old app writing some records and it works fine.

Our new app has a problem writing the same records on a test topic. We can not see the types of attributes in the JSON.

Let me give an example:

The old app writes the attributes as follows:

```
{
 ...
 "businesscode":
 {
  "string": "I2022416535"
 },
 ...
}
```

The new app writes the attributes as follows:

```
{
 ...
 "businesscode": "I2022416535"
 ...
}
```

This is an example for a `string` attribute but we have the same problem with `int`, `map`, `array`, etc. attribute types.

The used topic for tests has the same characteristics as the old app topic, and we use the same Avro file and same the generated objects.

What should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the Avro conversion. Avro JSON encoding states the type to be used for nullable/union fields.

https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding

Otherwise, your JSON libraries should at least be able to tell differences between Objects (Maps), Arrays, Ints, Strings, Boolean, and nulls.